# Not able to add id or class to the button tag in the in table

Tags: html, odoo-9

Hello everyone,
                I am not able to give a uniq identity to the button tag.
Here is my code..

```
<button class="btn-class" name="%(action_search_hotel)d"
        string="Search" type="action"
        icon="terp-gtk-jump-to-ltr"
         />
```

and here is the HTML code from the firebug...

```
<td class="oe_list_field_cell oe_list_field_action oe-button " data-field="247">
        <button class="" type="button" title="Search">
            <img alt="Search" src="http://localhost:8089/web/static/src/img/icons/terp-gtk-jump-to-ltr.png">
        </button>
    </td>
```

same is for id . I need these for copying the URL but not able to succeed

Comment: doesn't it should be `name="%(action_search_hotel)%"` insted of d at the end

Comment: @codenut then why class is removed? Although i am agreed with you.

Comment: @codenut  name="%(action_search_hotel)d" in this syntax d should be there since on this button click action is been called and new view has to be opened....and i want that url in one of the field of newly opened view for redirecting back in to the old view after completing the functionality

Comment: I am not familiar with odoo but i think  this link will help you https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-set-a-custom-css-class-on-a-field-in-a-form-view-97212 and i think i am here due to wrong tag  `jquery` `javascript` so put right  tags on your questions.

Comment: @codenut that's very kind of you .But I think these html have nothing to do with odoo(ofcourse functionality is based on odoo framework) but since i am working on javascript and jquery so had put those tag.But no offence .Thank you